# change cell format within functions in excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a function in excel vba. return value of the function is date, but function just return value of date in cell

how can I change format of cell to date (short date is preferred)

this is my code

```
Function ggg(rng As Range) As Date
ggg = rng.value - 466699
ggg = CDate(ggg)
End Function
```

Comment: I asked my question here:  https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1037840-change-cell-format-within-functions.html  but I didn't get my answer

Comment: You cannot change cell format by using function.

Comment: is there any library to do this?

Comment: You can format the cell using standard functionality to suit your needs. Can you explain the trouble you are facing currently?

Comment: I explained in next comment. `if my function return string I can't use my date normally. for example I can't use date filter or I can't add or subtract some days to it`

Comment: You will have to use a sheet based event like `Worksheet_Change` to handle formatting perhaps then.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change format of the cell with the function. You either need a subroutine or function that returns string. For instance:

```
Function ggg(rng As Range) As String
    ggg = Format(rng.Value, "yyyy-mm-dd")
End Function
```

Comment: thanks but if my function return string I can't use my date normally. for example I can't use date filter or I can't add or subtract some days to it

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the sheet tab and choose "View Code". Paste below provided code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In Target.Cells
        If cel.HasFormula And (InStr(1, cel.Formula, "=ggg(", vbTextCompare) = 1) Then
            cel.NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

And see if it helps your cause or not!

Comment: thanks but I don't have right to add code out of modules

Comment: @amiroo I do not understand your comment but that is what I could think of. Hopefully, someone else will be able to help you.